# Composite key validation in laravel 4

Tags: laravel

I've a composite key in my database. But I am getting error when submitting a form. I know why the error is happening because of the duplication to the primary key. But I don't know how I'll fix it in laravel 4.  Here is the schema

```
Schema::create('lecture_delegates', function($table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('lecture_id');
            $table->integer('delegate_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unique(array('lecture_id', 'delegate_id'));
        });
```

Here is the model.I've already use felixkiss, but it is not working.

```
class LectureDelegate extends BaseModel
{
    public static $unguarded = true;
    protected $table = 'lecture_delegates';
    public static $rules = array(
        'lecture_id' => 'required|unique_with:lecture_delegates, delegate_id',
        'delegate_id' => 'required'
    );
}
```

And controller:

```
class LectureDelegatesController extends BaseController {


    public function create()
    {
        $validation = Lecture::validate(Input::all());
        $lecture_id = Input::get('lecture_id');
        $delegate_id = Input::get('delegate_id');


        if ($validation->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('lecture', $lecture_id)->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }else {
            LectureDelegate::create(array(
                'lecture_id' => Input::get('lecture_id'),
                'delegate_id'=> Input::get('delegate_id')
            ));
            return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'Your are successfully apply to the lecture');
        }
    }
}
```

And form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' =>'create_lecture_delegate', 'method' =>'POST')) }}
                {{ Form::hidden('lecture_id', $lecture->id) }}
                {{ Form::hidden('delegate_id', Auth::user()->id) }}
                <p>{{ Form::submit('Apply') }}</p>
            {{ Form::close() }}
```

When I try to submit the form it showing this error message.

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-4' for key 'lecture_delegates_lecture_id_delegate_id_unique' (SQL: insert into `lecture_delegates` (`lecture_id`, `delegate_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 4, 2014-04-19 08:22:37, 2014-04-19 08:22:37))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a composite primary key for a table, you need to specify that when you are creating that table.

Please take a look at the [official documentation regarding indexes](http://laravel.com/docs/schema#adding-indexes)

In your case it will be :

```
Schema::create('lecture_delegates', function($table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('lecture_id');
            $table->integer('delegate_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->primary(array('lecture_id', 'delegate_id'));
            $table->unique(array('lecture_id', 'delegate_id'));
        });
```

Note the `$table->primary(array('lecture_id', 'delegate_id'));`